# How to remove newlines except the ones beside the text in python?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have text file containing numbers with different number of newlines. How can I remove the new lines except the ones.

Example of numbers I have in text file

```
1

2




3


4

2
```

If I do `open('thefile.txt').read().replace('\n', '')` I will get everything in one line. How can I get output like this.

```
1
2  
3
4
2
```

Comment: open('thefile.txt').read().replace('\r\n', '')

Comment: `[ line for line in open(file_path, 'r').readlines() if line.strip() ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better to just remove all lines that only contain whitespaces and join the remaining ones afterwards:

For example:

```
with open('thefile.txt') as myfile:
    result = '\n'.join([line.strip() for line in myfile if line.strip()])

print(result)
```

Or if you don't want to `strip` twice:

```
result = '\n'.join([line for line in map(str.strip, myfile) if line])
```

or using `filter` instead of a comprehension:

```
result = '\n'.join(filter(bool, map(str.strip, myfile)))
```